# comprehension over external range loses output type

Tags: range, list-comprehension, julia

Another newbie question, I find this difference very confusing:

```
it = 1:3
typeof([i^2 for i in 1:3]) # Array{Int64,1}
typeof([i^2 for i in it])  # Array{Any,1}
```

why does it matter where the range is defined?

`typeof([i^2 for i in it::UnitRange{Int64}])` seems to give a hint, as does [this discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7258). However, regardless  of the reason for the above behaviour, the practical question would be: how do I specify/enforce the output type of a comprehension?

Edit: A fuller example illustrates two separate issues,

```
# global namespace

nu1 = 0.5 + [0 ,1:3]
nu2 = 0.5 + (0:3)
typeof([besselj(_nu,[1,2]) for _nu in nu1]) # Any
typeof([besselj(_nu,[1,2]) for _nu in nu2]) # Any
typeof([besselj(_nu,[1,2]) for _nu in 0.5 + (0:3)]) # correct inference

# within a function

function rb()
  nu = 0.5 + [0 ,1:3]
  bj   = [besselj(_nu,[1,2]) for _nu in nu]
end

function rb2()
  nu = 0.5 + (0:3)
  bj   = [besselj(_nu,[1,2]) for _nu in nu]
end

typeof(rb()) # Any
typeof(rb2())# Correct inference
```

I first hit the issue within a function, where using a vector vs a range produces different output type, and while trying to resolve this I experimented in the global namespace and ran into the other issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following code

```
it = 1:3
@show typeof([i^2 for i in 1:3])
@show typeof([i^2 for i in it])

function foo()
    it = 1:3
    @show typeof([i^2 for i in 1:3])
    @show typeof([i^2 for i in it])
end

foo()
```

which produces

```
typeof($(Expr(:comprehension, :(i^2), :(i = 1:3)))) => Array{Int64,1}
typeof($(Expr(:comprehension, :(i^2), :(i = it)))) => Array{Any,1}
typeof($(Expr(:comprehension, :(i^2), :(i = 1:3)))) => Array{Int64,1}
typeof($(Expr(:comprehension, :(i^2), :(i = it)))) => Array{Int64,1}
```

Basically type inference is much harder in the global scope, and Julia mostly punts on it. This isn't typically a problem as all "real" code is well-scoped and not being run at the REPL. Array comprehensions *can* have type inference problems sometimes, although there is usually some reason (i.e. the thing you are "comprehending" over is not concretely typed, or the function you are evaluating inside the comprehension is not type-stable). You can always let Julia know what type the output should be using the usual syntax for a typed vector, i.e.

```
it = 1:3
x = [i^2 for i in 1:3]
@show typeof(x)  # typeof(x) => Array{Int64,1}
y = Int[i^2 for i in it]
@show typeof(y)  # typeof(y) => Array{Int64,1}
```

but I wouldn't expect to need this normally. Of course, some people like to be very explicit with their type assertions/declarations so you can use this if you want to be sure.

Comment: interesting, because I had the problem within a function :S

Comment: I've added something to address both those points. Do you have the actual code with the type inference problem?

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I'm trying to narrow it down to a minimal example.

Comment: OK, it seems to come down to an unlucky combination of two separate issues. I've added a more complete example.